# Add additional information under description in opencart

Tags: opencart

i want to add additional information under the description for every product in the product page. At the moment i have added custom tab for the additional information, but i want it to be right after the description. I guess i have to edit some code in the product.tpl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You have created Your own tab for that additional informaation You already had to edit the `product.tpl` template file, hadn't You?

Now the only difference between displaying the information in additional tab and after the description part is where You echo Your piece of data... So probably what You have so far is something like:

```html
  <div id="tabs" class="htabs">
    <a href="#tab-description"><?php echo $tab_description; ?></a>
    <?php if ($attribute_groups) { ?>
    <a href="#tab-attribute"><?php echo $tab_attribute; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($review_status) { ?>
    <a href="#tab-review"><?php echo $tab_review; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($products) { ?>
    <a href="#tab-related"><?php echo $tab_related; ?> (<?php echo count($products); ?>)</a>
    <?php } ?>
    <!-- YOUR OWN TAB -->
    <a href="#tab-mytab"><?php echo $tab_mytab; ?></a>
  </div>
  <div id="tab-description" class="tab-content"><?php echo $description; ?></div>
  <?php if ($attribute_groups) { ?>
  <div id="tab-attribute" class="tab-content">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php if ($review_status) { ?>
  <div id="tab-review" class="tab-content">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php if ($products) { ?>
  <div id="tab-related" class="tab-content">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
  <!-- YOUR OWN TAB -->
  <div id="tab-mytab" class="tab-content">
    <?php echo $my_tab_content; ?>
  </div>
```

Now what You only need to do is to move that `<?php echo $my_tab_content; ?>` right after the description (description tab):

```html
  <div id="tabs" class="htabs">
    <a href="#tab-description"><?php echo $tab_description; ?></a>
    <?php if ($attribute_groups) { ?>
    <a href="#tab-attribute"><?php echo $tab_attribute; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($review_status) { ?>
    <a href="#tab-review"><?php echo $tab_review; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($products) { ?>
    <a href="#tab-related"><?php echo $tab_related; ?> (<?php echo count($products); ?>)</a>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <div id="tab-description" class="tab-content">
    <?php echo $description; ?>
    <!-- YOUR OWN CONTENT HERE -->
    <?php echo $my_tab_content; ?>
  </div>
  <!-- ... -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add the same text on every product page, you can add it with 'welcome module'. Just put `<?php echo $content_bottom; ?>` in custom tab you added. Then create new welcome module in admin panel and place it at the bottom of product layout.